# Returning output values from a stored procedure to asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have an output value in my procedure called `result`, I want to make an if condition in asp.net that checks if `result = 1` and print a statement

```
public partial class ManagerViewTasks :  System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection( @"data source= DODO\SQLEXPRESS; " + 
        "Initial Catalog = Company_103; Integrated Security = True");

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sqlcon.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
            sqlcon.Open();

        SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("MG_Reviews_Task",sqlcon);
        sqlcmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@result ", SqlDbType.Int).Direction=ParameterDirection.Output;
        sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@re ", Txtname.Text.Trim());
        sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@task", TextBox2.Text.Trim());
        sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@proj",TextBox3.Text.Trim());
        sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@company",TextBox4.Text.Trim());
        sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@manager",TextBox5.Text.Trim());
        sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@res",TextBox6.Text.Trim());
        sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@deadline ",TextBox7.Text.Trim());

        sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        sqlcon.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlParameter result = New SqlParameter();
result.ParameterName = "result";
result.Value = 0;
result.Size = 1;
result.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(result);

sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
sqlcon.Close();

//Check result value here

if (result.value == 1){
//Do something;
}
```